# Can we delete Validation Rule through apex code?

Tags: validation-rule

I have got a User Story to delete all the Inactive Validation rules in Salesforce.

Instead of doing it manually I am finding another way(through Apex Code) to do it.

Comment: Metadata API can help you achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the validation rule by making REST request using below query -

```
/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,Active,Description,EntityDefinition.DeveloperName,+ErrorMessage+From+ValidationRule+where+EntityDefinition.DeveloperName+=+'Account'
```

And then you can delete it using metadata api.